# Failed to delete original file

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

we are running jar using batch file as window service and place xml files in `c:/processed` 
directory;

if xml has an errorneous format then move it to error folder; we are using below method to move the file to error folder but getting below exception.

I think when the process is running its not able to move the file to error folder .

```
FileUtils.moveToDirectory("a.xml", "c:/processed/error", false);
```

> exception in movedErrorFolder: Failed to delete original file 'c:/processed/a.xml' after copy to 'c:/processed/error/a.xml'

Comment: What about write permissions for this file?

Comment: What is the `FileUtils` class? It's not a class in the standard Java API.

Comment: I see you mention that you've been validating XML what are you using. Make sure you have relased the file after you validate it. We had an issue like this with JAXB

Comment: @Jesper I think `FileUtils` is part of the Apache commons-io

Comment: joey,how to release the file while unmarshalling with JAXB.

Comment: You could try running something like Process Monitor to see what's happening at an operating system level and possibly why the file couldn't be moved. You can download Process Monitor from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Answer (score 5):

1. The java process does not have the right to delete the file, but if you can write on it then you can delete it.
2. The file is locked by another process. This occurs typically when you write a csv open with Excel.
3. The file is locked by the java process self, close() the file before moving it.

Answer (score 2):

After  reader.close() put Thread.sleep() - It works like charm

```
reader.close();
// Thread is Explicitly made to Sleep as Threads were shared and files were not getting Moved.

Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another exception giving more details is probably nested in the Exception, held by the cause property

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you do not have the xml open in an editor/viewer or used by another process.

2) make sure you .close() before moving the file.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you opened a file inside the directory for read or write and you didn't call `.close();` before trying to delete the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this method from apache:

```
void org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(File srcFile, File destDir, boolean createDestDir)
```

e.g.

use this import

```
     import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

and your code would be like this:

```
  FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(new File("c:/processed/a.xml"), new File("c:/processed/error"), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this error since last 24 hours. None of the answers above worked for me. My operating system is Windows 7 64 bit and I am using JDK 6. I tried methods FileUtils.moveToDirectory as well as file.delete.

I suspected it had something to do with Java. I uninstalled and reinstalled JDK 6 (I ran the installer as an Administrator just to be sure) and restarted my machine and Eureka, the error disappeared and things started working.

Now don't ask me why I am still using JDK 6 in 2017 (Some enterprise software ****)